# I am unable to return a value depending upon my input parameters

Tags: java, android

I am creating a recycler view with 2 different layouts. But when I override the getItemViewType method the app keeps crashing whenever I try to return value depending on the position parameter. Ex -  I can have `return 1;` and it would work but not `return position % 2;`

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    String[] msgArray;
    Context context;

    public myAdapter(Context ct, String[] msg) {
        msgArray = msg;
        context = ct;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return 1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = null;

        switch (viewType) {
            case 0: {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_template, parent, false);
                return new MyViewHolder(view);
            }
            case 1: {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_page_row, parent, false);
                return new MyViewHolder2(view);
            }
        }


        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 0: {
                MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
                viewHolder.myText2.setText(msgArray[position].substring(1));
            }
            case 1: {
                MyViewHolder2 viewHolder = (MyViewHolder2) holder;
                viewHolder.myText23.setText(msgArray[position].substring(1));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return msgArray.length;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView myText2;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myText2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        }
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView myText23;

        public MyViewHolder2(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myText23 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msgFieldRight);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Can you post the stacktrace of crash here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {  
  return msgArray.get(position);
  }
```